# xCode build how to determine git branch?

Tags: android, ios, xcode, git

Suppose i'm working on a regular xCode project that has git tracking the files.

For internal usage purposes, i'd like to know (by looking inside at the iOS app running on the iphone) certain debugging information, such as what git branch the developer was on.

how could this be done?

on Android, you can modify the build script to look at the person's `.git` directory from where they've built and see something like `refs/heads/feature_branch_2` inside the `/.git/HEAD` file.

on xCode i have no idea what tool is even being used to build, let alone modify the build script. or... do i have to modify the build script? (i.e. is there an easier way?)

Comment: do want to know what ur current branch in git?

Comment: No clue on xcode, but you really want to embed the SHA, not the branch.

Comment: @d.i.v.a i want to know what branches the developers are on when i get crash reports coming in.

Comment: @AndrewC i want to know what branch, because they can have multiple commits. i just need the branch name to track down the issue

Comment: @David T. - trust me, I've gone down this exact same path.  Branches are temporary, SHAs are forever.  You want the SHA.

Comment: @AndrewC ohhhh i see what you mean. yeah, i guess someone could go and delete the remote branch. but doesn't github have a restore or something?

Comment: Not just that.  What if you make a new commit to the branch, or rebase, etc.  Or what if somebody makes a build with a local branch and you don't even know what the branch refers to.  If you want to debug you need the exact SHA, which will never change.

Comment: @AndrewC ah. well fortunately i don't need to debug their build, there's only a few main feature branches, and it's just to see what relevant feature it is on.

Comment: @DavidT. from command line u can check via `git branch` command.

Answer (score 0):

You can manage it via source tree MAC application and change gitignore path for manage conflict.

You can change gitignore path - SourceTree->Preferences->Git->Global Ignore List->Edit File.

You can manage various commits and all the thing via its GUI.

Comment: i think we're on slightly different pages here. i want to grab the branch name and have it available at runtime on an iOS app. does that make sense?